# ターミナルでマウスを使わず上下に移動する方法はありますか？

Tags: putty

**環境**
windows10
putty

ターミナルの移動について調べていたのですが行頭、行末まで移動することはできるようなのですが、たとえば以下のことができないようです

```
$ cd aaa
$ cd bbb 現在のカーソル
```

マウスを使わずに$ cd aaaがある行にいきたいのですがやり方はあるのでしょうか？ノートパソコンだったらトラックパットつかえばいいとおもうのですがデスクトップパソコンなのでそういうわけにもいきません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> マウスを使わずに$ cd aaaがある行にいきたい

カーソルを上下に移動して、過去の出力を確認したり、コピーしたい、ということでしょうか。その場合、 `screen` や `tmux` を利用することで、過去の出力を遡ったり、コピーやペーストを行うことができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今すぐ理解は難しそうなのでやる気がでてきたらやってみます

Answer (score 1):

カーソルを過去の行に移動して何をしたいのかにもよりますが、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>で実行した**コマンドの履歴**を遡ることができます(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>で逆順に表示)。

念のため補足しておくと、行頭・行末へのカーソル移動もPuTTYが実行しているのではなく、あくまで接続先(過去質問からするとCentOS)のシェルが受け持っている機能です。

Comment: 上下で履歴も一つの手ですね。CentOSが受け持っているという認識はありませんでした。長いパスがでてきたときにコピーしたいだけなので履歴をたどるのがいいかもしれないですね。気づきませんでした。ありがとうございます。